# appending to list within list gives AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, list, append

when executing the following code, I get the error message "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'". I know this error occurs when I try to append to an integer, for example, which is not the case here since I checked that via `type(section[len(section)-1])` which returned `list`

```
def increasing_section(a_list):
    section = [[a_list[0]]]
    i = 1
    while i < len(a_list):
        if a_list[i-1] < a_list[i]:
            section[len(section)-1].append(a_list[i])
        else:
            section.append(a_list[i])
        i += 1
    return section
```

Comment: what's the expected behavior from this line `section[len(section)-1].append(a_list[i])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from this line:

```
section[len(section)-1].append(a_list[i])
```

because at some point, when your if condition will not be met, the following line:

```
section.append(a_list[i])
```

will add an integer in section and the first line will produce error as `section[len(section)-1]` will be an integer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but to fix this you need to change `section[len(section)-1].append(a_list[i])`. Because `section[len(section)-1]` will return an integer and integer doesn't have `append` method, so if you want to insert an element to a list at a particular index, try `section.insert(index, value)`